# How to fix could not execute command 'lessc' in odoo 9

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, odoo-9

I'm using odoo 9 in Windows. I have installed nodejs for windows 64 bits and execute

```
npm install clean-css
npm install -g less
```

But every time it shows in my navigator could not execute command 'lessc'. How to fix this problem?

Comment: try with `npm install -g less-plugin-clean-css` as well

Comment: There is no difference even after restarting pc

Comment: any help please ???

Answer (score 0):

This always worked in my case:

```
npm install -g less less-plugin-clean-css
```

Hope this helps! Thanks.